# Does a visa extension count towards the 90 days?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, visa-extensions

We arrived in Greece on December 17, 2017. Our 90 days were up in March, but we were granted a type C visa extension to remain in Greece through June (refitting our sailboat).

Does this extension count towards the 90/180 rule or are we free to sail on to Italy in June? We are US citizens.

Thanks for the help. We've googled around and haven't found an answer.

Comment: Very good question!

Comment: @Stef For clarity, what is your citizenship?

Comment: Can you add a photo of your extension with personal details blacked out? Voting to close as unclear until then.

Comment: @Stef My understanding is that the 180 day period is a backward-looking time window. For any given day, you look backward into the previous 180 days (present day included) and count the number of days you were in the Schengen zone.  If that number exceeds 90, you’re an overstayer. This rule holds true even for non-visa nationals like Americans, Canadians, etc. This tool https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en might help you figure out the answer

Comment: @Traveller that's true, but does the extension have any effect on this?  If the extension counts as a residence permit under the Schengen codes (or as a long-stay visa, but that's unlikely since it was granted in Greece) then days spent in Greece authorized by the extension do not count in the 90/180 calculation.

Comment: Please add a scan of your visa with personal details blacked out for us to answer your question.